# cosinor2 package R error column 'Y' must be a 1d atomic vector or a list

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, gplots

I have been using `cosinor2` for my summer project and the scripts have been working fine without any issues.

But when i transfer the files to my supervisors pc and try to run the package everything works other than for the graphs that gets produced through serial sectioning. It gives me error of

```
"column 'Y' must be a 1d atomic vector or a list  ".
```

On my pc the graphs are produced without any issues but when i try to run the exact same script on my supervisor's pc I get the error.

Here is the script:

[image: the script]

And here is the error:

[image: the error]

Comment: Please provide the code and error as text rather than as a figure. Also give enough data to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error was due to the incompatibility of the cosinor2 package with the ggplot2's newest update. I updated the cosinor2 package today and this error doesn't occur anymore.